# Website font showing up different in mobile Safari

Tags: html, css, mobile, fonts, mobile-safari

I was testing my website on my iPhone 6 and noticed that one of my fonts looks significantly different, basically a completely different font. After searching and tweaking I have no clue what is going on.

This is the CSS for the font:

```
h1 {
  font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
  color: black;
  font-size: 52px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

In my actual CSS I link it like this, but apparently it is not necessary in jsfiddle: `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

**Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue:** https://jsfiddle.net/9uppfqqx/11/

This is how it looks on a desktop (Safari, Chrome, and Firefox):
[image: desktop]

This is how it looks on mobile (Safari - iPhone 6):
[image]

Comment: `font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;` defines the font you want to use for that element.  However, if the 'Great Vibes' font does not reside of the system of the person viewing your page a 'cursive' font will be substituted.

Comment: Didn't see your link reference, however when viewing your fiddle I see that as Comic Sans, neither Great Vibes or any other cursive font.

Comment: But when I add `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes` as a reference, shouldn't it download the font?

Comment: Based on Google Fonts your reference link should look like this -> `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`  You're missing the 's' in `https`.

Comment: I did notice that and I fixed it in the fiddle (and updated the link), but it still doesn't seem to be working. I fixed it in the question though.

Comment: Okay, so it turns out that using 'http' instead of 'https' was the problem, but I hadn't fixed it on my site because it still wasn't working in the fiddle, so I assumed that wasn't the true cause. I still don't understand why the fiddle isn't working, but it is now working on my site. Thank you!